# Declare and initialize after

Tags: c

I'm working on an exercise and I can't declare and initialize on the same line, and with these instructions I don't know how I can do, I tried multiple tips but no one works.
Can you help me please ? I want to initialize my array in the next line.
This, is working fine:

```
int tab[n];

tab[0] = 5;
```

And, this, is not working

```
int tab[];

tab[n] = { 0 };
```

Comment: "Compiler, I'd like an array of indeterminate size" is not going to happen. You'll need to use dynamic allocation for this.

Comment: I am agree with your reply, but I am a novice student and I dont know why I can t declare and initializing in the same line

Comment: The compiler needs to have an idea of how much space on the stack that array takes up before it can go any further. In an argument `tab[]` is valid, it's passed as a pointer anyway, but as a variable declaration it's woefully incomplete. No size? No dice. You can do `int* tab` and `calloc` it later. That's the only reasonable way to defer initialization here. The compiler can't go back in time and adjust the stack.

Comment: john zash, rather than an _array_ can code use an allocation like `int *tab = calloc(sizeof tab[0]. n);`?

Comment: In other words, either you know the size in advance and the compiler can allocate that for you on the stack, or you don't, in which case you put a pointer on the stack and allocate the actual array on the heap whenever you want.

Comment: You'll also need to know the maximum `n` you need to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue #1. The compiler needs a size when declaring an array.

```
int tab[];
```

Will not compile.

C does allow for variable sized arrays.

```
int n = 5;
int tab[n];
```

Issue #2. You attempt to assign to the nth element in an array with size n, which is out of bounds, and will not work.

Issue #3. You cannot assign to an array directly, so this will not work:

```
int n = 5;
int tab[n];

tab = { 0 };
```

And the initializer syntax will not work in this context. You would have to use it inline with the declaration. Although, a variable-sized array may not be initialized this way anyway.

Legal:

```
#define N 5

int main() {
    int tab[N] = { 0 };

    return 0;
}
```

Illegal:

```
int main() {
    int n = 5;
    int tab[n] = { 0 };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *C does allow for variable sized arrays*  Only in C99 - VLAs were made optional with C11. MSVC does not support VLAs in any form.  And MSVC isn't yet compliant with C99 (much less C11 or later...) in quite a few other ways, even with the 21st century almost 1/4 over...

Answer (score 1):

To *assign* an all zero byte pattern to `int tab[n]` after definition:

```
memset(tab, 0, sizeof tab);
```

If code needs a more complex assignment, code could then use individually for each array element as needed.

```
tab[0] = 5;
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but with your solution I need to do this: int tab[n]; But I can't do this

Comment: @johnzash How do you _define_ the array, if not with `int tab[n];`?  `int tab[];` is _not_ valid standard C.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ummm, MSVC?  ;-)  (No VLAs...)

Comment: @AndrewHenle OP implies a `n` sized array is desired.  Unless `n` is constant or VLA support exist, there is no solution for an _array_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica True.  OP: without VLA support `n` has to be **a** constant in C.  Mere `const` in something like `const int n = 5;` isn't good enough for C, unlike C++.  `n` has to be something like a literal `5` or `#define n 5`.

Answer (score 1):

C has something which is called flexible array members.

```
struct flex
{
    size_t size;
    int x[];
};

struct flex a = {5, {1,2,3,4,5}};

int main(void)
{
    struct flex *z;

    z = malloc(sizeof(*z) + 3 * sizeof(z -> x[0]));
    z -> size = 3;    
}
```

Comment: Initialization of a flexible array member, interesting - coding on the edge.  LSNED.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica -- ooh indeed. [C18 Standard - 6.7.2.1(20)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf#subsection.6.7.2) is silent on what occurs (struct size) if initialization of a FAM is attempted. The only formative example given shows allocation of the struct + FAM. I suspect this is highly implementation defined and in the event it's not handled by the implementation -- worse. And, since the standard is silent on it, no warning or error may be generated. This is a good issue.

Comment: I'm not so sure that's true, @DavidC.Rankin.  A strong argument could be made for this falling under paragraph 6.7.9/20-22.  "If the initializer of a subaggregate or
contained union begins with a left brace [...]" & "If an array of unknown size is initialized, [...]".  On the other hand, I do think this is one of those dark corners where implementation bugs like to lurk.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - I agree whole-heartedly. I don't have any definite answer here. The standard is a bit wordy in 6.7.2.1. I don't recall another section reaching for "*appertains*" (instead of applies). (6.7.2.1(9)). Generally when somebody uses a $.50 word, it is used to make up for lack of concrete substance.... This would make a good language lawyer question on its own. Good issue.

Comment: @JohnBollinger only static initialization. You cant do this for automatic storage duration objects

Comment: Well isn't that a buzzkill.  Although I can make a case for initializing a FAM being supported by the language spec, I don't think I can make one for it being allowed only for objects with static storage duration.  The provisions I'm looking at for support have no such limitation.  Presumably, then, the implementation in which you find such support thinks it is implementing an extension (and GCC documents exactly this behavior among its supported extensions).  That's fine, but it's not standard C, at least as far as that implementation is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify an empty pair of brackets to declare a variable.

```
    int tab[];  /* error */
```

And adding the assigment you add later, just gets things worse:

```
    tab[5] = 3;
```

The first thing you need to learn is that an assignment is some kind of expression that allows you to make a calculation, while a declaration is a statement (not an expression) that allows you to introduce a new object (and allows you to initialize it)

An initializer allows an incomplete declaration to become complete, so in the case you do both things at the same time (declare and initialize) the code above, written in this form:

```
    int tab[] = { [0] = 3, [1] = 5, [2] = 8 };
```

makes the array declaration to be complete and will initialize the elements as shown.

You can go further, and also specify an array length, and all the unspecified elements in the initializer will be initialized to 0 (in this case the object is complete from the declaration, but what is incomplete is the initializer, which fills the holes with zeros).

```
    int tab[20] = { [0] = 3, [1] = 5, [19] = 6 };
```

(if the indices will go up from 0, you can avoid the `[index] =` , as in

```
    int tab[20] = { 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6 };
```

)
Had you written your code as one declaration:

```
    int tab[] = { [5] = 3 };
```

that would have been valid.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NELEM(_arr) (sizeof (_arr) / sizeof (_arr)[0])

int tab[] = { [5] = 3 };

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NELEM(tab); i++)
        printf("tab[%d] = %d\n", i, tab[i]);
    return 0;
} /* main */
```

will show:

```
$ a.out
tab[0] = 0
tab[1] = 0
tab[2] = 0
tab[3] = 0
tab[4] = 0
tab[5] = 3
$ _
```